# Array of role in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I want to use an array to assign roles in Capistrano.

```
instances=ENV['deploy_hosts'].split ','
role :web, instances
```

("Undefined method match for array", blah blah blah)

```
instances=ENV['deploy_hosts'].split ','
role :web, *instances
```

("Connection failed for host1,host2" - duh, they're an ARRAY)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm not pretty sure but try:

```
instances=ENV['deploy_hosts'].split ','
instances.each do |instance|
  role :web, instance
end
```